# ElasticSearch index from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I need create index from mongodb. Colection name is `Product` and have such structure:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5239656f60663de206b1053e"),
    "brand": "<brandName>",
    "category": {
        "$ref": "Category",
        "$id": ObjectId("50cb515760663d3577000043"),
        "$db": "<dbName>" 
     },
     "image": "<imageUrl>",
     "integraId": "<someId>",
     "isActive": <isActive>,
     "name": "<productName>",
     "slug": "<slug>" 
 }
```

Collection `Product` have more 30 000 rows, but elasticsearch indexing only ~10 000 rows.
My query to create index:

```
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "servers": [
      { "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 27017 }
    ],
    "options": { 
        "secondary_read_preference": true
    },
    "db": "<dbName>",
    "collection": "Product"
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "test",
    "type": "test_type"
  }
}
```

And just a second question: How can I indexing only some fields (name, category (get row by id from other collection) and brand)?

Comment: And how many items are returned based on the above query of the Products collection? Maybe that query only has 10Kish items? As for the second, I'm not following you fully, but I think your talking about upsert. Not sure that's what you are going for though. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

Comment: I solve first promblem of specifying the required fields for indexing, but I do not know how to solve the second - to pull out another collection box and substitute it in the index
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346084/doctrine-conections-in-mongodb-to-elasticsearch-index

Answer (score 0):

You may have more luck in the Google Groups about it bro http://groups.google.com/group/elasticsearch/topics or in the IRC http://www.elasticsearch.org/community/

Comment: Thanks, but I would not ask this question if the answer is found in google

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has full text search built in experimentally in version 2.4 if you would like to experiment with that: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/ you may be able to query more effeciently. I realize this isn't the same as the elasticsearch solution you're looking for but this might be another way to solve the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks,ranman, but i hope that elasticsearch have nice solution for this issue, because compared to mongodb full text search, elasticsearch is very faster. And i think mongodb will not develop a search engine is further...

Comment: I understand. It can't hurt to experiment if MongoDB is already in your stack though. Good luck and the answer below mine about using the google group or irc channel may provide more info. Good luck!