# Doctrine connections in mongodb to elasticsearch index

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, elasticsearch

I'm use symfony2 with doctrine odm (mongodb). I need create elasticsearch index, but its not hard. My structure `Product` collection (abridged):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5239656f60663de206b1053e"),
    "category": {
        "$ref": "Category",
        "$id": ObjectId("50cb515760663d3577000043"),
        "$db": "<dbName>" 
    },
    "name": "<productName>"
}
```

`Category` collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("50cb515760663d3577000043"),
    "name": "<categoryName>"
}
```

Category field in `Product` collection - has 3 sub fields, which are created by doctrine. I need to create an index comprising only productName and categoryName.

How do I do that?